# Insert formula to excel with Ruby on Rails format xls support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xls

I am using the inbuilt "format.xls" support that comes with Ruby on Rails to export data to excel.

I have created my .xls.erb, and referenced values that I need. However, is it possible to insert a formula into a cell? eg. "=SUM(A1:A20)" I have not seen this used anywhere.

If possible, could an example be given?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=excel these screencasts may give you ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the direction of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx which was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The format used is

`<Cell ss:Index="2" ss:Formula="=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])">

    <Data ss:Type="Number"></Data>

</Cell>`

This will sum the values in the range 3 rows above to 1 row above, in the current column. The formula uses R1C1 format rather than A1-style formatting. This link is particularly useful for getting to know the elements and attributes that make up the schema - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx